# jstl - choose/when

Tags: jsp, jstl

i have short code:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${logging==1}">
    write 1
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    write 2
</c:otherwise>

</c:choose>
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work. Doesn't matter if logging is 1 or 0, code display me 'write 2' text.

What is wrong? logging is **int**

After your answers a've changed my code to:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${logging eq 'added'}">
    write 1
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    write 2
</c:otherwise>

</c:choose>
```

now, my '***logging'*** is a String. It's display '**added**' and ${logging['class']} display '*class java.lang.String*', but it still write **'write 2'**

i also have <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> declaration

My **web.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Comment: Is "logging" bounds with session or request?

Comment: What servletcontainer are you using?

Answer (score 2):

That can happen if the value is not an `int` at all, but for example a `String`. For strings, you'd need to quote the comparison value:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${logging == '1'}">
        write 1
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        write 2
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Another possible cause is that EL is simply not evaluated. That can in turn happen if your `web.xml` root declaration is wrong. See also the bottom of [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for proper declaration examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain if the "${logging==1}" syntax is correct.

I have definitely seen e.g. "${logging eq 1}" syntax before in this type of code.

Also - is the variable logging definiitly defined properly?

Can you show the rest of the code if possible?

Comment: ${logging == 1} is correct. I even prefer this over ${logging eq 1}, since is more readable for me.